# Articles detected, currently not indexed

Tags: indexing, google-search-console

does anyone have the same problem as me ? Almost everytime i am publishing a new article, it is not indexed and i have got this error on google search console : “detected, currently not indexed” and it can last more than 6 months ; I am wondering what is causing this problem… My configuration is : Ovh – Wordpress – Yoast seo – Elementor ; It is not duplicate content.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please share more details - how is this related to programming?